# Submersion implies many rational points in image?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields, rational-points, dimension-theory

Let $A \colon V \to W$ be a surjective linear map 
(defined over $\mathbb{Z}$),
inducing a projection 
$\alpha \colon \mathbb{P}(V) \to \mathbb{P}(W)$. 
Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}(V)$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}(W)$
be some absolutely irreducible projective varieties
(defined over $\mathbb{Z}$) that we know well.

Suppose that when considered over large fields, the restriction of the map $\alpha$ is close to a surjection.
For example, suppose that $\alpha$ restricted to $X$
is a submersion almost everywhere when considered as a differentiable function over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

My question is whether or not such a behaviour implies that we can deduce that $\alpha$ is close to being a surjection also over finite fields.

> How to produce a lower bound on the number of 
>   $\mathbb{F}_p$ points of $\alpha(X)$?

Is there a standard procedure of how to pass from information over
$\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$
to answering the above question? 
Could someone please point out some relevant theorems? 
Which other properties of $\alpha$ restricted to $X$ should one prove in order to obtain the desired lower bound?

*Remark 1:* The concrete example of $X$ that I have in mind is a product of Grassmannians.

*Remark 2:* I am aware of the fibre dimension theorem, saying that over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$, the generic fibers are of the same dimension. Together with Lang-Weil estimates, this would bring us close to giving an answer, as long as one could say something about the *set over which generic fibres are*, the fact that *the fibres are absolutely irreducible* and have *known dimension* (that is, the same dimension as they have over $\mathbb{C}$). Are any of these known?

Comment: I think it would be good to clarify more the question. By "local submersion", do you mean on the level of $\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{C}$-points? The analogue of submersion in algebraic geometry is a smooth morphism, so are you asking that $X \to Y$ is a smooth morphism of schemes? This in itself is a very mild assumption, as by generic smoothness it always holds over some open subset of the base (in char $0$). And when counting $\mathbb{F}_p$-points, one is often happy to remove closed subvarieties as these usually contribute negligibly to the count.

Comment: Usually $A \colon V \to W$ surjective  is considered as inducing an immersion , $ \alpha \colon \mathbb{P}(W) \hookrightarrow  \mathbb{P}(V)$.  Is that a typo or do you want to do it that way.

Comment: @DanielLoughran: Indeed, as an analytic function. I have edited the relevant part in the post. Would smoothness be enough to give an answer to the question? How is smoothness over $\mathbb{F}_p$ related to that over $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @aginensky: I really want to have a rational map $\mathbb{P}(V) \to \mathbb{P}(W)$ coming from a surjective linear map.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are after and I think that the submersion condition you are imposing is not as important as you think it is. For example the map $x \to x^2$ on the affine line is a smooth morphism away from the origin, hence a submersion on points over these fields, but is clearly not surjective on $\mathbb{F}_p$-points. The image contains $(p-1)/2$ many points; is this a "good enough" lower bound for you?

Comment: @DanielLoughran: It would certainly suffice if we can conclude that the number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points is $O(p^{\dim Y})$, so a sensible bound on the log-size of the image would be fine. You don`t think it is of any use that the map $\alpha$ is essentially linear and so its fibers are linear intersections with $X$? By the way, I would be satisfied with resolving this even just for large enough primes $p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an attempt at an answer to what I think the question is (please tell me if anything isn't clear).

> Theorem
>
> Let  $f:X\to Y $ be a dominant morphism of finite type schemes over $\mathbb{Z}$ with $X_{\mathbb{Q}}, Y_{\mathbb{Q}}$ geometrically integral of dimensions $n,m$, respectively. Then there exists an absolute constant $c$ such that
> $$ \#f(X(\mathbb{F}_p)) \geq c p^{m} + O(p^{m-1/2})$$
> for all sufficiently large primes $p$, where the implied constant in the big-$O$ is independent of $p$.

To prove this, we use the following key lemma.

> Lemma
>
> There exists an absolute constant $c'$ such that for all $y \in Y(\mathbb{F}_p)$ we have
> $$\# f^{-1}(y)(\mathbb{F}_p) \leq c'p^{\mathrm{dim}\, f^{-1}(y)} $$

There are a few ways to prove this lemma. It can be proved using the Lang-Weil estimates, Deligne's proof of the Weil conjectures, or the method given in the answer to [Number of solutions to polynomial congruences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294234/number-of-solutions-to-polynomial-congruences/294253#294253). (The key point here is that Deligne proved that the resulting sheaves which arise are constructible; this is what allows one to obtain the stated uniformity in the absolute constant $c'$).

Proof of the Theorem: There exists a proper closed subset $Z \subset Y$ such that every fibre outside of $Z$ has dimension $n-m$ (this follows from Lemma 36.28.1. of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05F6 applied to $f: X \to Y$). Moreover the number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points in $Z$ is at most $c''p^{m-1}$ for some absolute constant $c''$. Thus replacing $Y$ by $Y \setminus Z$, we may assume that the dimension of every fibre of $f$ is exactly $n-m$. Thus by the key lemma, we have
$$\# X(\mathbb{F}_p) = \sum_{y \in f(X(\mathbb{F}_p))} \# \{ x \in f^{-1}(y)(\mathbb{F}_p)\} \leq c'p^{n-m}\#f(X(\mathbb{F}_p)) $$
However, by the Lang-Weil estimates, we have
$$\# X(\mathbb{F}_p) = p^n + O(p^{n-1/2})$$
as $p \to \infty$, since $X_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is geometrically integral. The result now easily follows with $c = 1/c'$. $\Box$

Remark: The constant $c$ depends on the number of irreducible components of the generic fibre of $f$ over the algebraic closure. In particular, if the generic fibre of $f$ is geometrically integral, then you can take $c = 1$.

Comment: Great, this is just what I was looking for! Thank you very much! I would be grateful for some additional explanations regarding the key lemma. I will state them as separate comments.

Comment: 1. (dimensions) There are several dimensions appearing, over $\mathbb{F}_p$, $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$. These all come from Noether normalization of the ring of regular functions of the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$. (I am assuming everything is affine.) Are these dimensions all the same if the prime is large enough? (I understand that as long as $p$ is large enough, algebraic independence of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ implies independence over $\mathbb{F}_p$, so at least these two dimensions eventually agree.)

Comment: 2. (the constant) Over a fixed point $y$, we can get the required bound with the constant basically coming from the algebraic part of Noether normalization. Could you please elaborate on why this constant can be chosen to be universal? (In principle it could happen that by varying $y$, the constants might grow.) I have looked at the answer you linked to and I unfortunately do not understand what you mean by "spreading out". Could you please provide me with a reference?

Comment: 1. I don't quite understand this comment. If $V$ is a variety over a field $k$ and $\bar{k}$ an algebraic closure of $k$, then $\mathrm{dim} V = \mathrm{dim} V_{\bar{k}}$. Also some of the fibres of $f$ can have larger dimension, but this can only occur on some closed subset $Z$ as in my answer. If you like, I'm putting all the bad primes into the closed subset $Z$.

Comment: 2. Whilst certainly the key lemma is well-known to experts, it is difficult to find/write out a complete rigorous proof (which is why I avoided doing so in my answer :)). Whilst one can probably do by applying a uniform version of Noether normalisation to each fibre, I would probably try to prove it using Deligne. I'm not sure of the best reference for these kinds of arguments, but you can find them used in the proof of Lemma 3.6 from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01817.pdf

Comment: As for spreading out: I would recommend Section 3.2 of Poonen's book "Rational points on varieties".

Comment: BTW: In https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/the-lang-weil-bound/, Tao  proves a version of the key lemma and calls it a "Schwarz-Zippel type bound"

Comment: Perfect, the Schwarz-Zippel type bound will do just fine in this situation. The constant will depend only on the degree of the fibre. Thank you!

Comment: There is another detail that is not clear to me. I would be grateful for a clarification, and I apologize for the ignorance. Both schemes $X$, $Y$ are "fibred" over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. We can set $U$ to be an open subset of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ such that for every $(p) \in U$, we have  $\dim X_p = n$, $\dim Y_p = m$ and all fibres over an open subset $V$ of $Y$ are of dimension $n - m$. All of these come from the fibre dimension theorem. ...

Comment: ... Now, for every $y \in Y_p$, there is an open subset $U_y \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ such that for $(p) \in U_y$, we have $\dim f^{-1}(y)_{p} = \dim f^{-1}(y)_{\mathbb{Q}} = n - m$. I do not see why $\bigcap_{y \in Y_p \cap V} U_y$ is open in $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.  That is, when $y$ varies, the fibres $f^{-1}(y)_p$  have dimension $n-m$ only for $p$ large enough (depending on $y$), and it could happen that this bound grows indefinitely.

Comment: You don't apply the fibre dimension theorem to each of these morphisms separately, you apply it to just the morphism $X→Y$. The only property you need here is that the morphism $X→Y$ is of finite type (See the answer to this question: mathoverflow.net/questions/193/…)

Comment: Applying the general upper semi-continuity theorem will produce a good open subset of $X$. I am struggling to see how you then produce the open subsets in $Y$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. Are the projections from $X$ to both of these supposed to be open or closed?

Comment: I'm not claiming that the set of points in $Y$ with this property is open; only that there exists an open subset of $Y$ with this property. The image of the open set of $X$ in $Y$ is dense and constructible; now just play around with it to get the open set in $Y$ which you want. I have no idea why you are asking about open subsets of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, as I'm not claiming anything about the existence of any such open subset.

Comment: I see, so this is how we get the open set $V=Y-Z$ in the image of $U\subseteq X$. Thank you! The reason I am mentioning $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is that I am still lost with why the full fibre over $V$ should be of the right dimension. Are you saying that $V$ can be shrinked in such a way that $f^{-1}(V)\subseteq U$?
Or that $X - U$ can not project onto $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$? The fibres can be larger over certain primes and I do not see how you deal with absolutely bounding the bad primes. This is why I thought one should consider the projection to $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your comments. You seem to be trying to compare my answer with a flawed argument you have in mind. I'm not claiming anything which is not already stated in my answer. BTW, standard practice on this site is to accept an answer if you are happy with it, so that the system knows that it is answered and does not keep bumping it to the home page.

Comment: I corrected some minor typos and added a few more details (including a reference to the stacks project).

Comment: Great! As far as I am concerned, your answer is now complete. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You're very welcome!